# Prevent Grub resolution reset during startup

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, display

I have set a custom Grub resolution, but around 3 seconds into the boot sequence the display reverts to the native screen resolution.

The screen is a small but high-resolution touchscreen (13", 3200×1800). I have added the following lines to `/etc/default/grub` before running `sudo update-grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noquiet nosplash"
...
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

Grub displays at the requested resolution, and the boot sequence output initially displays at the same resolution, but just before asking for the LUKS passphrase the display flips back to the full native resolution, which is illegibly small for me.

The boot sequence is too fast for me to pinpoint exactly when the change occurs, but it's sometime around the touchscreen being detected:

```
[    2.495843] usb 2-4: Product: Touchscreen
[    2.495847] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: ELAN
...
[    2.878743] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/...
[    2.878896] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/...
[    2.879000] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/...
...
[    3.053233] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. ...
...
[    3.065796] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
[    3.095533] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
```

How can I configure the system to continue displaying the boot sequence output at low resolution?